# Oracle Database Mobile Server Accessing via Web Browser

Tags: oracle, mobile, glassfish

I am newbie to the Oracle Database mobile server. I could able to set up the DMS server and MDK following this vidoe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXoVLgbY5bk,also I have setup the Oracle database express edition on local host and every thing seems to be just fine. I have chosen glassfish4 as my application server.
The server port number I have mentioned while deploying mobile repository is 8081 and I am trying to open console using the following url
http://localhost:8081/mobile/console
But I am getting 404 error.But when I open a specific file it opens perfectly. But it wont show me Mobile Manager Login page at all. Am I missing any prominent configuration? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

After going through different steps and approach , finally it got resolved. I have installed correct version of glassfish server and It started working. http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1/release/glassfish-4.1.zip